# How can I reach the login screen from inner nav file

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-navhostfragment

I'm a rookie in Kotlin and Android.

My application has two different navigation structures. The first one is a navigation file named main_activity_nav, which contains splash, login, signup, and main fragments. The second one is named bottom_bar_nav, which includes cart, profile,favorite, and home fragments.

Fragments of bottom_bar_nav(like Profile Fragment) are showed by a navhostfragment in main fragment(it's in main_activit_nav, you can see at the below image).

Structures like that

[main_activity_nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txRMV.png)
[bottom_bar_nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xR8pM.png)

You can think that main_activity_nav upper navigation,bottom_bar_nav's lower.

There is a button for signout in my profile fragment, and when I press it, I want to return to the login screen and delete all fragments in the backstack.

My button function

```
    binding.signOutButton.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.signOut { result ->
            if (result) {
                //Navigation process (Profile to Login Fragment and clear backStack)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried;
val navHostFragment = requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragment) as NavHostFragment
navHostFragment.navController.navigate()

I tried some combination of these code but I got result null or junk

Comment: The host for the second graph shouldn't be a fragment, try having one Activity for each graph, like LoginActivity with login_nav.xml and MainActivity with main_nav.xml. Then you can go to login with Intent. Also make sure to add proper flags to delete backstack so the user can't go back!

Comment: Thank you so much, ı suppose that this is better way.I’ll try.but cannot we do only one activity? I just wonder

Comment: As I said, you should have a graph for each Activity with FragmentContainerView but if you're using multiple graphs with one activity you can add them as nested graphs (ex: you can add bottom_bar_nav inside main_activity_nav) 
Check this for more info: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/nested-graphs